# updating record based on set if condition in gorm

Tags: mysql, go-gorm

I am trying to update the records in my Go project when trying to do so there is some need to update based on the conditions. I have figured out a way in mysql but that query need to be converted into gorm. Heere is the mysql query:

`update table_name SET field_name1 = IF (field_name2 = 2, 1 , 0) where field_name3 = 6;`

Comment: What you tried so far for gorm? This mysql query works properly ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done this using

```
query := fmt.Sprintf(`UPDATE table_name SET field_name1 = IF (field_name2 = "%s", 1 , 0) where field_name3 = "%s"`, field_value1, field_value2)
    
s.DB.Exec(query)
```